# Simulate slow connection on localhost

Tags: php, apache, xampp, localhost

I'm using xampp and I'm trying to simulate a slow connection so that I can test out a few things that I've done with image uploading and progress bars.

I've tried using Fiddler and mod_bw, both of which didn't work for me (mod_bw is a bit outdated, I'm not even sure if it works anymore).

Does anyone know how I could simulate a slow connection on localhost?

Comment: You could set some `sleep()`'s into your PHP code?

Comment: That just delays things, not slow them down.

Comment: Well, in my world slow = delayed execution :)

Answer (score 4):

Try using Charles Proxy, very good tool for web debugging and it has a bandwidth throttling feature which sounds like it would help in this case.